# Conditional formatting google sheets with true false

Tags: google-sheets-query, conditional-formatting, highlight

I am trying to highlight cell A5-G5 using conditional formatting. The range I am applying is A5:G90 with custom formula =if(H5:H90,TRUE). However it's only highlighting just A1. How can I highlight it across A5-G5?

Comment: what condition is it that you are looking to meet? your formula doesn't include anything such as this rule would =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,A1)>1 See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en